# Balanced Parentheses Program Python: Match Function Returning Incorrect Value

Tags: python, dictionary, return, compare, parentheses

so I'm trying to do the "are the string of parentheses balanced?" program in Python and while my balanced function is working properly, the function that I created to check if the parentheses are a match is returning incorrect values. I'm going to attach the whole code, comments and all so that you can see. The first way I tried to do it was with conditional if/else statements. For that approach I kept getting False even if the parentheses were a match. For the second approach I kept getting TypeError: . This is my code.

```
from collections import deque
```

stack = deque()

#dir(stack)

#use a stack to see if an input string has a balanced set of parentheses

#function that tells which parentheses should match. will be used later

def is_match(paren1, paren2):

```
#dictionary for more efficiency rather than a bunch of conditionals
#match_dict = {
   # ')': '(',
   # ']': '[',
   # '}': '{'
#}

if paren1 == '(' and paren2 == ')':
    return True
if paren1 == '[' and paren2 == ']':
    return True
if paren1 == '{' and paren2 == '}':
    return True 
else:
    return False


#print(match_dict[paren1] == paren2)
#return match_dict[paren1] == paren2
```

def is_balanced(string):

```
#start with an iterative for loop to index through the string 
for i in string: 
    
    #check to see if the index of the string is an open parentheses, if so, append to stack
    if i in '([{':
        stack.append([i])
        print(i)
        
    #if index is not in substring, check to see if string is empty 
    else:
        if len(stack) == 0:
            return 'not balanced'
        else:
            match = stack.pop()
            if is_match(match, i) == True:
                return 'balanced'
            else:
                return 'not balanced'
```

string = ('([{}])')

is_balanced(string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stack.append(i)` instead of `stack.append([i])` to add the element `i` to the  deque:

```py
def is_balanced(string):
    # start with an iterative for loop to index through the string
    for i in string:

        # check to see if the index of the string is an open parentheses, if so, append to stack
        if i in "([{":
            stack.append(i)  # <- HERE!
            print(i)

        # ...
```

If you want to extend the deque by appending elements from an iterable argument (`[i]`), use `extend`:

```py
stack.extend([i])
```

See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for more information.